# Как экспортировать избранное?

Tags: internet-explorer, браузер

Как экспортировать избранное из IE в другие браузеры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В IE выбираешь Избранное -> Импорт и экспорт -> Экспортировать в файл -> Ставишь галочку Избранное -> Выбираешь самый верхний пункт -> Выбираешь папку для сохранения.

В другом браузере в диспетчере закладок выбираешь импорт и указываешь файл.

Comment: Вы уверены, что у всех браузеров одинаковый формат экспорта закладок?

Comment: Абсолютно.

Answer (score 1):

Вот [сервис экспорта](http://www.web-zakladka.ru/index.php?page=stat&ids=expo) закладок.

Answer (score 0):

обычно при установке браузера они сами спрашивают или нужно сделать импорт из IE

Comment: Вы устанавливали IE?

Comment: > Вы устанавливали IE?

причем тут одно к другому ? По описанию задачи IE уже установлен.

зы: IE это не броузер.

Comment: > зы: IE это не броузер.

Ну да.